# How i can mount code folder in Docker Volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker, after a few changes my app work flowless locally, but when I try to put it on the server things are different. On the server, I use Ubuntu+ Docker and Portainer for GUI.

i tried many configuration for volume settings and volume in services.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/services/app
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/var/www
  # Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./docker/services/web
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  # Database
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  # Database Management
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.1
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - PMA_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - PMA_PORT=${DB_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
  # Caching
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - redis-volume:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  # Mailing Server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
volumes:
  app-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "./src"
  db-volume:
  redis-volume:
```

[image: Structure]

Laravel app is in src folder.

Tests that i tried
On Volume:driver_opt:device :

```
device: ./src
device: "./src"
device: "$PWD/src"
```

On Service: app/web:

```
    volumes:
      - "./src:/var/www"
- app-volume:/var/www
- ./src:/var/www
```

I don't understand why local is ok and o server is not.
Maybe some portainer settings? but what?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to overwrite your images' code with the contents of a named volume, and one image's code looks like it might be getting overwritten with the code from the other.  Does it improve things to remove all mentions of the `app-volume` volume?

Comment: why do you need two containers with the same volume ? Also you cant have the same destination directory for multiple mounts/volumes.